# Nuxt + Elastic Beanstalk: why is the host header value an IP address only on certain subdomains?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Nuxt Universal application deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk through the CLI. A wildcard subdomain is set up through Namecheap, so our clients can access their site at `client-name.mycompany.com`. I also have SSL set up through ACM, and I have an application load balancer on my EB instance.

In my nuxtServerInit action, I make an API call to a URL that is built from the value of host header, like so:

```
async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    apiService.init(process.env.ROOT_API);
    const data = await vendorDirectoryAPI.getDirectoryId(req.headers.host);

    // logic

    commit("setDirectoryData", data);
  },
```

**The problem that I am having is that for about 10% of the subdomains, the API call fails. Looking through the logs, the problem for the failing subdomains is that the value of `req.headers.host` is an IP address. For the other 90%, the value is as expected: `client-name.mycompany.com`.**

What's happening here? Is there a better way that I could get the URL that  the user is visiting? Do I have to do some custom nginx configurations? Should I try setting up a new environment?

Any suggestions, hints, etc. would be very much appreciated, I am relatively new to Elastic Beanstalk (and AWS in general).

Please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide that would be helpful, I'm sure there's something that I failed to include.

Comment: Do you have any blue/green or weight type routing setup for your domain? 10/90 split may indicate that the dns provider routes 10% of requests to test address, and the 90% to primary one. This is often done with blue/green or canary type deployments?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the reply! No, I do not have anything like that in place. I just have a single environment that was setup through the CLI while I have been finishing up development.